# Move transform with speed in KPH and get transform speed in KPH

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I am moving a transform in KPH Speed and aim to get its speed in KPH also (for testing purposes)

Here is the way to **move a transform with speed in KPH**. Its 160 KHP.

```
 transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 160f / 3.6f * Time.deltaTime);
```

Here, is the code snippet that **getting the speed in KPH**

```
public double Speed;
    private Vector3 startingPosition, speedvec;

    void Start()
    {
        startingPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        speedvec = ((transform.position - startingPosition) / Time.deltaTime);
        Speed = (int)(speedvec.magnitude) * 3.6; 

        startingPosition = transform.position;
        //text.text = Speed + "km/h";  // or mph

    }
```

Now can someone tell me that where is the problem? **Either i am not   moving the transform correctly or getting speed in kph is not right?**

How do i move an object with speed in KPH and get its speed in KPH as well.

Comment: If your world units are meters, then this looks good. Except maybe for this `(int)` cast. If you have widely varying framerate, you might get inaccuracies, depending on the order you call these methods. What results do you get?

Comment: Yes my worlds unit are in meters. Unity3d game -egine measurment are in meters.but the problem is both speed are not same. The resultant get speed is not exactly 160 which i am setting.

Comment: @NicoSchertler my framerate is stable not varying too much. I am setting the speed (KPH) in Update event and getting the speed in LateUpdate event.

Comment: And what speed *are*  you getting instead of the 160 kph?

Comment: Its ranging from different , some time 90 94 150 200 , changing quickly

Comment: I'm guessing you need to log some values. Just track the times and distances your calculation uses. Maybe you will see some anomalies there. Do you really use `LateUpdate` instead of `FixedUpdate` like in the code? Also, make sure that your transform is a rigid-body transform. But that would not explain the high variance. It is probably related to timer synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

what does this do? :)

```
speedvec = ((transform.position - startingPosition) / Time.deltaTime);
```

i read:

```
/*distance vector from start position*/ totalDistance=(transform.position - startingPosition).magnitude
```

and why this?

```
/ Time.deltaTime
```

distance/time in last frame?(deltaTime=last frame execution time)

So solution:
if you are using constant speed:

```
speed =totalDistance/totalTime;//distance since Start()/time since Start()
```

if you are not using constant speed you should register position in one frame and calculate speed using its position in next frame, so you will have:

```
speedInThisFrame=distanceInThisFrame/Time.deltaTime;
```

How would I do it:

- use a rigidbody;
- use rigidbody's velocity to move it;
- its a vector,    so
  `rb.velocity=transform.forward*speed*Time.deltaTime;` 
  to move your object's rigidbody. //where speed rappresents the distance in m your rigidbody will travel in 1 second.
- speed in m/s. = rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;

Comment: `rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime` - LHS and RHS units don't match...

Comment: its an assignment, not an equation :) (Vector3 velocity= Vector3 vector*float*float)
or i didn't understand your comment?

Comment: `rb.velocity` has units of speed (= distance / time), whereas the RHS expression has units of speed **x** time (= distance). Is this what you intended?

Comment: rb.velocity is a Vector3, its magnitude will rappresent the speed in m/s, this is what i indended

Comment: My point is, `speed * Time.deltaTime` has units of *distance*, not speed.

Comment: Oh, there speed is intended as float that rappresents [distance in meters traveled in 1 second] . its probably my unity professional deformation, sorry if i was unclear, for me was so obvious i didn't even think about a problem there :).